# PYTHON. Cómo armar una función que devuelve todo lo que esté entre comillas en un texto

Tags: python

Qué tal? Recién estoy empezando y estoy intentando armar una función que si yo le doy un texto como:

```
*effsfs "Egfgd" gdgfdf 2fdbfdbfd "ewrew" dgdgdfdf "tgf"  3ergf k"3" dsfgsdgfs "54"*
```

Me devuelva exclusivamente las partes del texto que están entre comillas, separadas por un salto de línea, es decir:

```
"Egfgd"
"ewrew"
"tgf"
"3"
```

Comment: Bienvenido Bruno Costanzo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Por favor agrega el código de lo que hayas intentado hacer hasta ahora, es fundamental para que te pregunta sea bien recibida. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Hola de esta manera se puede lograr lo que deseas:

```
def buscar(text):      
  import re
  matches=re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"',text)
  #Esto matches ['String 1', 'String 2', 'String3', 'sas']
  #retorna una cadena con cada palabra encontrada con doble comilla en una sola linea
  return ",".join(matches)

def agrega_comillas(a):
    return '"{0}"'.format(a)
salida = buscar('Esto es un "String 1"  "String 2" con varios strings "String3" de prueba"sas" ')
#salida: String 1,String 2,String3,sas

#convertir la cadena de 'salida' a una lista de 'palabras' removiendo la coma
palabras = salida.split(',')
#imprimir lista de palabras con doble comillas
for palabra in palabras:
    print(agrega_comillas(palabra))

#salida:
"String 1"
"String 2"
"String3"
"sas"
```

Saludos.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string
- https://www.techiedelight.com/split-string-into-list-python/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208090/python-how-to-append-double-quotes-to-a-string-and-store-as-new-string